# Exchange 2010 oversized mail notification

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, ndr

Earlier we have Exchange 2003. In exchange 2003 when set the maximum size of sending / receiving mail, we can set an e-mail address where we see a notice if we have an undeliverable mail.

Now we changed our servers, and our Exchange 2010 we can't find where should be set this up?!

Now if someone send us an oversized mail, we can't see anything. In the message tracking log i can see the ndr about the oversized mail, but i would like to set an administrator mail address to get this notifications too.

Is it possible somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to configure external postmaster address. For details, see [this article](http://msundis.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/configure-postmaster-microsoft-exchange-recipient-and-ndr-forwarding-in-exchange-server-2007-and-2010/)

Comment: i set the two (same internal, is it problem? ) address what you suggested. And set two ndr codes:4.4.7 ; 5.2.3.  (refering to this site: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2010/exchange_2010_ndr.htm) But still dont't get copy from NDR messages to my admin address

Comment: The test mail from my gmail to my internal mail: the mail received without attachement

Comment: I manage the maximum message size in the: Server Config/Hub transport / Receive connectors / Myconnentor.
And i managed per/mailbox
Should i config under Transport setting too?

Comment: Does this configuration work for you with another DSNs (for example for 5.1.1 - RecipientNotFound)? I have exact same configuration as in the article, but currently I am unable to test if it works for 5.2.x (Message Too Big)